# zsh module_init error everytime I open terminal on macOS (Monterey)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, macos-monterey

Every time I open the Terminal app, I'm met with

`/Users/YuriSP/.zshrc:1: module_init: function definition file not found dr.mac@YSPs-MBP ~ %`
instead of (example) `Last login: Thu Jan  20 10:50:23 on ttys000  dr.mac@YSPs-MBP ~ %`

What can I do to fix this??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you open the Terminal app, it reads your `~/.zshrc` file and runs any commands in it. To troubleshoot where the error is coming from, I would open the file, then see if the source of the error is obvious. It looks like it might be on the first line?

Try commenting out that line by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line, then quit and restart Terminal and see if the issue goes away.

If you don't know how to edit your `~/.zshrc`, read my guide that goes over various ways to [open and edit hidden files on a Mac](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/5-ways-to-open-hidden-files-on-your-mac/?utm_source=stackoverflow).

If the first line wasn't the culprit, then comment out half of your `~/.zshrc` and see if the issue goes away. Then keep commenting out more chunks until you narrow it down.